# Eclipse 3.5: Implementing my own context menu for a MultipageEditorPart --> no viewer involved

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In my current RCP-project i use a `MultipageEditorPart`. It has various pages, with simple SWT composites on it. The composites contain some Text and Combo elements. When the user right clicks onto the editor page, I want a context menu to open. This menu holds a command for creating a new editor page, with a composite on it.

The command is already working, but I'm quite clueless about how to implement the context menu for the editor. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

This should be based on Action contributions: see [**Contributing Actions to the Eclipse Workbench**](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html)

As an RCP-based example, You could check out "[Designing a Workflow Editor Eclipse XML](http://translate.google.fr/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.developpez.com%2Fakrogen%2Fp7995%2Fplugin-eclipse%2Fconception-d-un-editeur-eclipse-de-work-17%2F&sl=fr&tl=en)", where a contextual menu is added to an `EditorPart`, included in a `MultipageEditorPart`.

```
protected void createContextMenuFor(StructuredViewer viewer) { 
   MenuManager contextMenu = new MenuManager("#PopUp"); 
   contextMenu.add(new Separator("additions")); 
   contextMenu.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true); 
   contextMenu.addMenuListener(this); 
   Menu menu= contextMenu.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl()); 
   viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu); 
   getSite().registerContextMenu(contextMenu, new UnwrappingSelectionProvider(viewer)); 

   }
```

[image]

See also [Step 18](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.developpez.com%2Fakrogen%2Fp8032%2Fplugin-eclipse%2Fconception-d-un-editeur-eclipse-de-work-18%2F%23deleteWithContextualMenu) for extending that context menu (section "Delete - Contextual Menu, requiring using GEF).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I'm trying not to use any actions. As far as i understand this, the extension point "org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus" was replaced in eclipse 3.3 by "org.eclipse.ui.menues". And in your example you are using a structured viewer, while i'm not using any. 

Do i have to use viewers or is there some other way to get the commands on the context menu? 

But anyway thanks for helping me. :-)

Comment: @Patrick: this is right, the example is a bit old. I will look a bit more into this.